# nativescript textfield ngModelChange

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

```
<GridLayout row="1" columns="*">
<TextField hint="Station name" col="0" [ngModel]="stationName" (ngModelChange)="stationTyping($event)"></TextField>
</GridLayout>
```

This is giving error:

```
Found peer TypeScript 2.0.10
12:31:01 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.

Error: watch /var/www/html/train-locator/node_modules/adm-zip/headers ENOSPC
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1036:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1429:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1456:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:407:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:455:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:460:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
```

Sometimes it gives error on one node_module and sometimes on another mode_module. What does this error mean?
what could be possibly wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
ENOSPC === no space left on device
```

This often happens when using emulators created with 200MB space (default value) and you have already installed multiple applications (which in debug mode are larger than in release and 200mb is often not enough space for testing multiple applications)/. The solution is to either edit your emulator to use more space or to remove some installed applications.

Comment: I'm using android phone, and it has more than 2GB of free space left. And this problem is coming after I have upgraded nativescript to 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Hi: here how i use the event listener to capture the input value.

```
//template...
<TextField 
        #revqrt
        [(ngModel)]="fd_recqty" 
        keyboardType="number">
</TextField>

//ts file

...
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
...

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
 this.$qtyListener= fromEvent(
     this.receiptQty.nativeElement, 'textChange')
     .debounceTime(400)
     .subscribe((event:any) => {
        console.log(event.value); //this this input value
  });
}
```